# Python. Не получается отправить уведомление через Pushetta

Tags: python

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time
import urllib.request as urllib2
import json

GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN) #Read output from PIR motion sensor 
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT) #LED output pin

def sendNotification(token, channel, message): 
data = { 
"body" : message, 
"message_type" : "text/plain" 
} 

req = urllib2.Request('http://api.pushetta.com/api/pushes/{0}/'.format(channel)) 
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json') 
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Token {0}'.format(token)) 

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))

while True: 
i=GPIO.input(4)
if i==0: #When output from motion sensor is LOW 
print("No intruders",i) 
GPIO.output(10, 0) #Turn OFF LED 
time.sleep(0.1) 
elif i==1: #When output from motion sensor is HIGH 
print("Intruder detected",i)
sendNotification("108961cb497296f38064f13feccc9b1f3d35b53e", "Chinga111", "Hello World").encode('utf-8')
GPIO.output(10, 1) #Turn ON LED 
time.sleep(0.1)
```

**TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.**
В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

Вы передаете строку `json.dumps(data)`, а необходимо `bytes`. Вызовите у строки метод encode для преобразования в `bytes`